# If condition with operators execution in c++ and python

Tags: python, c++, execution

Simple question of how execution happens in C++ and Python.
If I have an if condition

```
if ((b == c) and (a == b))
```

My doubt in the above condition is,
if first part i.e. `(b == c)` is **false**
then the second condition i.e. `(a == b)` is executed or no matter what first part output was, second parts gets executed irrespective of that.

Answer (score 4):

Both in c++ and python, `and` and `or` operations support [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), that is, if the left part of `and` is false, the right part is not evaluated; if the left part of `or` is true, the right part is not evaluated.

In c++ this is per standard (§5.14/1):

> The
>   &&
>   operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to
>   bool
>   (Clause
>    4
>   ).
>   The result is
>   true
>   if both operands are
>   true
>   and
>   false
>   otherwise. Unlike
>   &
>   ,
>   &&
>   guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is
>   false**

and (§5.15/1):

> The
>   ||
>   operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to
>   bool
>   (Clause
>    4
>   ). It
>   returns
>   true
>   if either of its operands is
>   true
>   , and
>   false
>   otherwise.  Unlike
>   |
>   ,
>   ||
>   guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation; moreover, **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to
>   true**
>   .

In python that is also mentioned in the docs ([python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)):

> `x or y   |   if x is false, then y, else x  (1)`
>   `x and y  |   if x is false, then x, else y  (2)`
>
> Notes:
>
> (1) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is False.
>       (2) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is True.

Comment: Thanks for great insights.!